# How I can register IP address of micro service

Tags: microservices

So I have for example a list of micro services

In one micro service I need to make a call in to another, and I need to know ip adress, lets say I have some micro service REGISTER where I store host:ipdaress of all my services but how I can put this IP's to REGISTER micro-service ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends heavily on your infrastructure. You could go for a service directory like consul.io, where you can request an endpoint (ip & port) for an instance of a service. Another option would be to trust on DNS to resolve the services for you, for example via SRV records. Either way, this is not something that should be solved inside the microservice itself.

Comment: but if I need to make a call inside microservice 1 to microservice 2?

Comment: Then Microservice#1 needs to resolve the address to Microservice#2 via the infrastructure.
If you would go for docker & consul then check out the consul registrator at https://gliderlabs.com/registrator/latest/user/quickstart/. It listens to all docker containers that are being started and registers them as services in consul.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building microservice, the best way to go through is dockerizing the application and hosting in Kubernetes or something similar which would provide load balanced service url's.